# Powershell command in PHP

Tags: php, powershell, powercli

I'm trying to be clever and create a form to create a VM in ESX.

I have found the PowerCLI add-in for Poweshell and i have manually managed to create one.

This is my code but I'm struggling to make it work.

```
{
// Get the variables submitted by POST in order to pass them to the PowerShell script:
$name = $_POST["name"];
$diskmb = $_POST["diskmb"];
$MemoryMB = $_POST["MemoryMB"];
$NumCPU = $_POST["NumCPU"];
$connectesx = "Connect-VIServer -Server IPADDRESS -Protocol https -User 'USERNAME' -password 'PASSWORD'";
$createvm = "New-VM -Name $name -DiskMB $diskmb -MemoryMB $MemoryMB -NumCPU $NumCPU";
$psScriptPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\Infrastructure\vSphere PowerCLI\esxdhb.psc1";

// Execute the PowerShell script, passing the parameters:
    shell_exec("powershell -psc $psScriptPath -command $connectesx && $createvm");
    echo ("$name Created Successfully.");
```

Comment: Don't try to be clever, it results in Remote Code Execution vulnerabilities.

Comment: I don't know you environment, but I would be extremely skeptical that this implementation of a webpage to create a VM is a good idea. Access controls, auditing, hard coding credentials in your script... Proper orchestration is important. Can and should are very different.

Comment: Also to expand on point raised by @Narf `NumCPU = "1; Get-VM | Remove-VM"`